# Checkbox onChange() event triggered twice only on Android(Gingerbread 2.3)

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox, android-2.3-gingerbread

When the selectAll checkbox is tapped, the onChange() event is triggered twice.

This happens only on Android devices with Gingerbread(2.3). On other devices and desktop browsers the event is triggered only once.

Here is the script which I'm using.

```
    /* Check-Uncheck */
    self.elements.listview.on('change', ':checkbox', function (event) {
      var unchecked = $(':checkbox:not(:checked)', self.elements.listview);
      self.elements.selectAll
        .prop('checked', unchecked.length === 0)
        .checkboxradio("refresh");
    });


    /* Check-Uncheck 'Select All' */    
    self.elements.selectAll.change(function () {
      var checkboxes = $(':checkbox', self.elements.listview);    
      var checked = self.elements.selectAll.is(':checked');
      checkboxes
        .prop('checked', checked)
        .checkboxradio("refresh");
    });
```

Please let me know if anyone has faced this particular issue, or have any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: try `.off('change').on('change', function ()....` edit: also replace this `self.elements.selectAll.change(function () {` with `.on('change')` like on check-uncheck code.

Answer (score 0):

well, i can't determine the source of the problem...maybe the onclick handler doesn't get overwritten...but an easy workaround would be a lock variable...

```
var lockCheck = false;

//in onchange code of both functions:
if(lockCheck){
    lockCheck = false;
    return;
}
lockCheck = true;
```

[edit] ...well...or Omar's suggestion :)